# How to move the column to the center position, and bring it to the place of another column in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

World!

I have some question about changing position of columns in bootstrap

I have to change position of first column with logo to the center and show up at left of window hamburger menu icon on mobile.

For more information look at the image under post:
[Image on imgur here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rSEi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you upload code

but as far as i understood from image, you can try following :

```
<div class="col-xs-2 hidden-md">Navigation</div>
<div class=" col-md-2 col-xs-8 ">Logo section </div>
<div class="col-md-8">Navigation</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">Search box</div>
```

Comment: that wouldn't work because he wants his logo centered in all cases, this way his logo will go on left when not on mobile

Comment: I don't think so.
At least in image it appears that logo is on left, on desktop

Comment: Yeah. This solution is the best!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-xs-2 ham">hamburger</div>
<div class="col-xs-8">logo</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">search & cart</div>

.ham * {display: none; }
@media (max-width: 47.9em) { 
.ham * { display: block; } 
}
```

I don't see how it is related to changing the positions of columns..

Answer (score -1):

you can use a @media query and write the css for the mobile version of your site in that query. 
Basically your code will be something like

```
@media(max-width: 767px) {
    /* css code */
```

}

Comment: Hi, why the downvote? Did I not follow some norms? Or was the answer not useful? Thanks.